# Java Servlet Mysql Blob image

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

Hello guys i am trying to build a web app, in which users will be able to upload a picture on their profile. So i have the table users and the image as a blob in a row on this table and now i am trying to retrieve it, using a java servlet, but i only get a small blank square.my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Profile extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    try{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
                 ("jdbc:mysql://195.251.267.131:3306/****","****","****");

    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
              ("select * from users where email=?");
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
if(session!=null){
String email=(String)session.getAttribute("email");
Blob photo = null;                    
    ps.setString(1, email);

    ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
  photo = rs.getBlob(1);
  }
  response.setContentType("image/jpg");
  InputStream in = photo.getBinaryStream();
  int length = (int) photo.length();

  int bufferSize = 1024;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

  while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    System.out.println("writing " + length + " bytes");
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
  }

      in.close();
  out.flush(); 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe step through with the debugger and check what is received and then write it here? You should also check your client side to make sure it sends something.

Answer (score 0):

I see some possible causes in your code:

- Do not set contentType=text/html at the beginning. It's no use.
- The right [mimetype for jpg images](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image) is `image/jpeg`.

Additionally, I also suggest these minor fixes:

- Do not initialize `length=photo.length`. It's no use.
- Use buffer sizes multiple of 4096. It's more efficient.
- Appart from doing `out.flush()`, you should also close the opened streams (`out` and `in`), preferrably in a try-with-resources instruction:

`try(OutputStream out=response.getOutputStream())
    {
        ...
    }`

Same for JDBC resources: connections, statements and resultsets.

- You should think of an alternative behaviour when session==null. For example, throwing a `ServletException` with a describing message.

Comment: i tried the fixes you suggested and temporarily removed if(session!=null), the result i get is still the same little bordered blank sqare on the top right of my page

Comment: Ples test your servlet by calling to it directly from the browser address bar: `http://server:port/context/servlet`, and see what is the response returned by the server.